React component is increasing in memory usage overtime from rendering? Is there a conflict or memory leak?
Here's my component, what happens is I connect to my websocket and listen for incoming messages from the server and display them. Whenever my message list exceeds 10 messages, I slice the first element and add the new one. My array confirmed does not exceed a length of 10 elements, and the data of each message is fairly small.
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000?uid=React");


export default function Discord () {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

    ws.addEventListener("message", data => {
        if (messages.length >= 10) {
            setMessages(arr => arr.slice(1,arr.length).concat(JSON.parse(data.data)));
        } else setMessages([...messages, JSON.parse(data.data)]);  
    });
                                        
    return(
        <div class="bg-gray-900 rounded-lg h-full w-full">
            <div class="relative overflow-y-scroll scroll-smooth xl:h-4/5 h-5/6 top-0 w-full">
                <div class="absolute">
                    <MessageList messages={messages}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
function MessageList ({ messages }) {
    const messagesEndRef = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView()
    });
    return (
    <ul class="">
        {messages.map(message => <DiscordMessage messageData={message}/>)}
        <div ref={messagesEndRef}/>
    </ul>
    )
}

I can also confirm that it is this component, as I have removed it and monitored the memory usage and its stable at around 600mb. Whenever I enable this component it climbs up to 6gb then usually just crashes Firefox.
Does the memory issue stem from me rendering components incorrectly?

ws.addEventListener("message", data => {
  if (messages.length >= 10) {
    setMessages(arr => arr.slice(1,arr.length).concat(JSON.parse(data.data)));
  } else setMessages([...messages, JSON.parse(data.data)]);  
});

This is in the body of your component, so every time Discord renders you're adding an additional event listener. These never get cleaned up. You will need to move it into a useEffect, and add a cleanup function.
Additionally, you are currently checking for messages.length before you call setMessages. This would require you to put messages in the effect's dependency array. That's not the end of the world if you've implemented the cleanup function correctly, but it would be better to move it inside the call to setMessages, and then it does not need to be in the dependency array.
useEffect(() => {
  const onMessage = (data) => {
    setMessages((arr) => {
      if (arr.length >= 10) {
        return arr.slice(1, arr.length).concat(JSON.parse(data.data));
      } else {
        return [...arr, JSON.parse(data.data)];
      }
    });
  };
  ws.addEventListener("message", onMessage);
  return () => ws.removeEventListener("message", onMessage);
}, []);




Thank you!! This definitely resolved it from crashing it entirely. Thank you so much
Interesting note to this, not sure how it might be related but the memory explodes in Firefox to roughly 1.7gb, but its stable. However chrome runs at around 400mb-500mb.
